# Is there a function to find the max values index in an array containing ints and strings?

Tags: ruby

In the example here, is there a way to print out the max int (7654) index (5) properly?
I havent been able to figure out a way to do this with an array containing ints and strings, only ones with strictly ints.

```
array = ["me", 2345, "you", 345, "him", 7654, "her", 25]
arraybutonlynumbers = [2345, 345, 7654, 25]

puts array.each_with_index.max[1] #comparison of Array with Array failed (ArgumentError) 
puts arraybutonlynumbers.each_with_index.max[1] #no error
```

Comment: What is your logic for determining the maximum? E.g. what makes `7654` bigger than `"you"` in your example?

Comment: @seasonalz : Why don't you simply loop through the array (using `each_with_index`) and manually calculating the maximum, as soon as an element happens to be a number?

Answer (score 1):

### Using Select, Max, and Index

You can find the intermediate results you need in three conceptual steps using built-in Array methods:

1. Use [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-select) to consider only Integer values.
2. Capture the largest Integer value with [Array#max](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-max).
3. Search the original Array for the captured Integer, and return the index of that element with [Array#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-index).

You would then use some or all of those return values to craft your expected output. To illustrate the general approach from the irb console:

```
# find largest integer in a mixed array
array.select { |e| e.is_a? Integer }.max
#=> 7654

# find index of last return value
array.index _
#=> 5
```

However, to get the output you want, you'll need to refactor this into something that keeps the intermediate results so you can return them in the format you expect. For example:

```
def max_integer_with_index array
  max_int = array.select { |e| e.is_a? Integer }.max
  max_int_idx = array.index max_int
  [max_int, max_int_idx]
end

max_integer_with_index [
  "me", 2345, "you", 345, "him", 7654, "her", 25
]
#=> [7654, 5]
```

You can also reduce finding the index to a single line of code if you don't need the intermediate values. For example:

```
array.index array.select { |e| e.is_a? Integer }.max
#=> 5
```

#### Caveat

Please note that if you want to do something else besides ignore the String objects in your array, you will probably need to implement [Array#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) (inherited from Enumerable; see also [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Comparable.html)) to draw your own custom comparisons between Integers and Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ["me", 2345, "you", 345, "him", 7654, "her", 25]
element, index = array.each_with_index.max_by{| el, idx| el.to_i}

p element, index
# => 7654
# => 5
```

Note however that `to_i` converts strings which do not start with a digit to `0`, which may produce unwanted results if there are no positive integers in the array.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines but haven't come up with a nice way of dealing with `array = ["me", -2345, "you", -345]`. I suppose one could write `array.each_with_index.max_by{| el, _| el.is_a?(String) ? -Float::INFINITY : el }`, but that's kinda ugly.